# JSP - Netbeans cannot use session bean

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

Solved: if you run in trouble like me doublecheck your constructor definition!
mine was for some ninja-releated reason private.

Hi everyone,

i'm new to NetBeans-JSP programming (i'm quite confident with PHP)
hi have this instruction in "doLogin.jsp":

```
...
<jsp:useBean scope="request" id="user" class="minibay.user.LoginBean" />
<jsp:useBean scope="session" id="userSession" class="minibay.user.UserSessBean" />
...
```

when I run the application and go to the page I recive this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /doLogin.jsp(12,0) The value for the useBean class attribute minibay.user.UserSessBean is invalid.
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:148)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1220)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UseBean.accept(Node.java:1178)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3416)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:231)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:347)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:589)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
  org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Actually, the class is located under "MiniBay/java/minibay/user" (where MiniBay is the project root)

I've read in other post that my classes should be located under the "WEB-INF" folder.
Actually, ii've tried to move them with no succes.

Furthermore, the "user" bean works well, if I remove the second line of the code above I have no problem.

Any Idea of how to make it work out?

thnks

Edit: this is the UserSessBean class definition:

```
package minibay.user;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *
 * @author Alessandro Artoni <artoale@gmail.com>
 */
public class UserSessBean implements Serializable{
    private boolean loggedIn;
    private User user;

    private UserSessBean(){

    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return loggedIn;
    }

    public void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
        this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The value for the useBean class attribute minibay.user.UserSessBean is invalid.*

This boils down that the following has failed miserably:

```
UserSessBean userSession = new UserSessBean();
```

Does it have an (implicit) public no-arg constructor? It should be there to get construction to work. Also take care that any of (static) initialization blocks runs without throwing runtimeexceptions/errors. You should however have seen that back in the server logs as root cause.

#### See also:

- [Javabeans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) - This specifies how Javabean classes should look like

Comment: I'm gonna check the log with more accuracy, anyway, I've added the class definition; as you can see it does have public no-arg constructor

Comment: Oh, I'm really stupid, after double checking I realize the constructor wasn't public Oo.

Comment: You're welcome. You can by the way also just remove it if it doesn't do any business and you don't have another constructors taking arguments.

Comment: Oh,that's good news =) My teacher telled us we MUST put that usefull constructor - i tought that the implicit one would be ok, but, as he told me, I put it there. Thankyou again ;)

Comment: Well, then just put it in (and earn points! :) ). I didn't mean to imply that it's bad. Just that it's actually optional if there are no other c'tors. General consensus in real world is however indeed to explicitly specify one yourself since that ends up in more consistent code and better maintainability (adding other c'tors later wouldn't then lead to surprises because you accidently overlooked the default c'tor).